# Gulp rev-del not removing files

Tags: gulp, gulp-rev

do I understand this wrong or is something not right here?

I have this piece of code

```
gulp.task("minifyScripts", function () {
  return gulp.src("assets/scripts/*.js")
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/scripts/min'))
    .pipe(rev.manifest())
    .pipe(revDel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/scripts'))
    .pipe(livereload())
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

My understanding was that this should remove old .js file when one with new hash is created, but its not...

Do you have any idea? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify either dest in the options, or base in the manifest options—unless you're writing everything to the root directory.
Try:

`pipe(revDel({dest: "assets/scripts/min"})`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `rev-del` has a number of users, including myself, who are unable to get the plug-in to delete the old static files after `gulp-rev` hashes them.

Switching over to [gulp-rev-delete-original](https://github.com/nib-health-funds/gulp-rev-delete-original) simply worked OOB.

In the OP's use case, the updated solution would be:

```js
const revDel = require("gulp-rev-delete-original")

gulp.task("minifyScripts", function () {
  return gulp.src("assets/scripts/*.js")
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(revDel()) // call just after rev()
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/scripts/min'))
    .pipe(rev.manifest())
    //.pipe(revDel()) ==> move to just after rev()
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/scripts'))
    .pipe(livereload())
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```